# Implement Pseudo Naked Constraints

Tags: rust

I'm working on flushing out dependency injection (DI) in Rust. I have something working, but I'm trying to make it *better*. As I understand, Rust does **not** support *naked constraints* with type parameters (as some other languages do). I'm trying to determine whether it is possible to *fake* naked constraints in an unsafe way (assuming that's necessary). I'm completely ok with epic fail for an incorrect mapping. My understanding in Rust is simply that I need to convince it that `T` does implement `U` and can be cast to it - implicitly or explicitly. By *cast*, I mean a concrete, but generic, type can be cast to a trait object because it implements it (I realize most people ask for the other direction and I understand the complexities there).

Including everything I have would be a bit much; however, here's some context. Consider that we can boil down a factory function to (this works):

```rust
Rc<dyn Fn(&ServiceProvider) -> Rc<dyn Any>>
```

Currently, I have a builder that looks something like (abridged):

```rust
pub struct ServiceDescriptorBuilder<TSvc: Any + ?Sized, TImpl> {
    _phantom_svc: PhantomData<TSvc>,
    _phantom_impl: PhantomData<TImpl>,
}

impl<TSvc: Any + ?Sized, TImpl> ServiceDescriptorBuilder<TSvc, TImpl> {
    pub fn from<F>(self, factory: F) -> ServiceDescriptor
    where
        F: Fn(&ServiceProvider) -> Rc<TSvc> + 'static, {
        // convert to factory
        let factory = Rc::new(move |sp| Rc::new(factory(sp)));
    }
}
```

This completely works for something like:

```rust
let descriptor = ServiceDescriptorBuilder::<dyn Foo, FooImpl>::new(/* unimportant */)
                  .from(|sp| Rc::new(FooImpl::default()))
```

My goal is to remove the additional `Rc` declaration in the factory closure. **All** instances are wrapped in `Rc`. A transient lifetime always gets a fresh `Rc` with count 1, while a singleton has a cloned `Rc`. What I want to be able to do is (e.g. minus the `Rc`):

```rust
let descriptor = ServiceDescriptorBuilder::<dyn Foo, FooImpl>::new(/* unimportant */)
                  .from(|sp| FooImpl::default())
```

I can get the second, simpler variant to compile, but it fails at runtime - for somewhat obvious reasons. I need to convince Rust to use `Rc<dyn Foo>` with an owned value of `FooImpl`. This just doesn't seem to be possible with generics. Perhaps it's possible with associative types, but that's only an option if it still results in a succinct syntax. What really escapes me is the *magic* the compiler itself can do. It seems to have no problem understanding that `Rc<FooImpl>` is covariant and can satisfy `Rc<dyn Foo>`.

I have something working so this isn't really blocking, but it really irks me that this is not achievable in a simpler form. Perhaps it's just a current limitation in the language. Some other languages would allow this to be expressed as `where TImpl: TSvc`. I won't pretend to understand why this is *hard* or not yet supported, but other languages have figured it out. I'm aware that there is already a limitation that you cannot constrain a type to a trait. Perhaps that's the only feature needed to make this more succinct.

I'm content with waiting, but it seems there is some albeit unsafe way to make `Rc` own an instance of `FooImpl`, but expressed as `Rc<dyn Foo>`. Unless I have a gross misunderstanding, this is what the compiler is ultimately producing. It's unclear to me how to force or replicate that.

I'm not excited to use a macro to solve this, but I'd consider that as an acceptable solution; especially, if it can be hidden away as an implementation detail (from callers/devs). While my current solution does work and is more verbose, it does provide some level of compiler checks because you can't just return *anything*. A more concise syntax that removes this check (with `transmute` or something) might not be worth the trade-off.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm summarizing correctly, you basically want to go from a concrete type `FooImpl` to a trait object `dyn Foo` but in a generic setting (in this case through `Rc`).

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn to_dyn<DynTrait, Impl>(i: Rc<Impl>) -> Rc<DynTrait> {
    // ... some implementation
}
```

There is no existing constraint that can do this in stable Rust. You would have to manually implement something like a `ToDyn` trait for each type you want to use; probably not ideal. I do not know a way to do this otherwise even unsafely.

---

However this can be done on nightly via the [`Unsize<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) trait.

```
#![feature(unsize)]

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::marker::Unsize;

fn to_dyn<DynTrait: ?Sized, Impl>(i: Rc<Impl>) -> Rc<DynTrait>
where 
    Impl: Unsize<DynTrait> // `Impl` can be "unsized" into `DynTrait`
{
    i
}
```

This is part of [RFC 982: DST Coercion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md) which itself is part of the larger [RFC 401: Type Conversions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md).

Comment: You got it. I've definitely avoiding _Nightly_ since I have something working. It seems like it's just a current limitation. I also forgot to mention the case of _Self_, which really means there's two possible constraints. `TImpl` is some struct that implements `TSvc` **or** `Tmpl` _is_ struct `TSvc`. Even though there's no inheritance in Rust, there's still use cases for injecting a concrete type via a struct.